# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_job'

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, scrapy, scrapyd

I am trying to use **scrapyd** with scrapy.

When I use this the code below it works fine.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from shikari.items import shikariItem
from scrapy.http import Request


class Radiate(scrapy.Spider) :
  name = "run"

  allowed_domains = ["google.com"]
  start_urls = ['http://google.com']

  def parse(self, response) :
    item = shikariItem () 
    sel = Selector (response)
    item['url'] = response.url
    return item
```

**But when I use it with selenium, it doesn't**

```
import scrapy
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from shikari.items import shikariItem


class Radiate(scrapy.Spider) :
  name = "run"

  allowed_domains = ["google.com"]
  start_urls = ['http://google.com']

  def __init__(self):
   display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
   display.start()
   self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')  

  def parse(self, response) :
    item = shikariItem () 
    item['url'] = self.driver.get(response.url)
    return item

  def teardown(self): 
    display.stop()
    self.driver.close()
```

My spider never runs. In jobs it gets listed under finished, and on error log I see `exceptions.TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_job'`.

Here is the full error log

```
2016-02-23 19:42:06 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-02-23 19:42:06 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-02-23 19:42:06 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'shikari.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'file:///var/www/html/shikari/scrapyd-client-master/items/shikari/run/82776010da6511e5b08d1288e0cebe8d.jl', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['shikari.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'LOG_FILE': 'logs/shikari/run/82776010da6511e5b08d1288e0cebe8d.log', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 4}
2016-02-23 19:42:06 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-02-23 19:42:06 [twisted] ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2016-02-23 19:42:06 [twisted] ERROR: Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 153, in crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1237, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1099, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 70, in crawl
    self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 80, in _create_spider
    return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 50, in from_crawler
    spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
exceptions.TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_job'
```

What do I need to do so I don't get the error?

Comment: can you post the full stack trace ? There is no occurrence of `_job` in your example code.

Comment: Nor, in fact, does any code get run in the example.

Comment: @AndreHolzner sorry about the confusion, the problem seems to happen when using selenium, updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You redefined `__init__` in your subclass and changed it's signature from `scrapy.Spider`. You also didn't call `scrapy.Spider`'s `__init__` method.

`scrapy.Spider` [source for **init**](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.0/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L17-L25)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any argument in your **init** method. Just add ****args*** and *****kwargs***.

```
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
        display.start()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
```